# Any support for this Shita Mikubetzes?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rishonim

The Shita Mikubetzes in Neddarim, top of 2b reads like this:

מאי שנא גבי נדרים דתני כולהו. בכמה מקומות מקפיד התלמוד על כדומה לזה ושואל 'מאי שנא' כי הכא, ובכמה מקומות אינו שואל. לפי שדרך התלמוד להקשות כך במקום שיש ליתן טעם בדבר, אמנם במקום שאינו יודע טעם בדבר אינו מקשה.

Basically, what he is saying is that this specific type of question and  answer format in the gemara is reserved for where the gemara has an answer for us. Presumably,  asking this where "they didn't know an answer" (his words, not mine) would not help us in understanding anything any better.

Is there anyone who wrote something akin to this that he might be quoting? Or perhaps not quoting, but someone who's way of thinking we can line this up with?

Comment: I think I've seen this elsewhere. Not sure where, off hand (tosfos?).

Comment: @Yishai I checked the basic Rishonim on the page and in the back. I didn't see anything. But it could be I missed it.

Comment: It might not be on that Mesechta, but another which asks the same structure of question. Then again, I could be remembering the Shita Mikubetzes, so ...

Comment: Althogh not directly related, as an example of viewing the Gemara as more of a literary phenomenon, similar to the Shita that the question asked was a springboard to an answer, Rashi in Megillag 3a (the top) writes that the Gemara uses rhetorical questions as a literary device. See also the Ritva in Megillah 2b regarding the hava amina that walled cities are totally exempt (If I recall he says that this isnt a real question, but rather asked so the reader can see that no alternative explanations exist, similar to Rashi).

Comment: I can't pinpoint now, but many _tosafos_ come to mind.